# When drawing graph in graph-tool only vertices appear, no edges

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, graph-tool

I have created a graph (`graph1.xml`) which I have saved in a previous script. I have now loaded that graph and am trying to draw it. When I type the following in python2.7 (on Ubuntu):

```
load_graph('graph1.xml')
```

I receive a message saying:

```
<Graph object, directed, with 10194124 vertices and 25920412 edges at 0x7fbb837a2e10>
```

So the graph object clearly contains a lot of vertices and quite a number of edges. Thus I proceed to execute the following code:

```
g = load_graph('graph1.xml')
root_vertex = find_vertex(g, g.vp.vprop, '774123')
root_vertex = root_vertex[0]
graph_draw(g, pos=radial_tree_layout(g, root_vertex), output="test-radial1.png")
```

Which returns message saying:

```
<PropertyMap object with key type 'Vertex' and value type 'vector<double>', for Graph 0x7fbb83747410, at 0x7fbb837476d0>
```

When I open the folder in which I have run the code a file by the name `test-radial1.png` does appear, however it seems to only show some vertices: [image: output from graph_draw]

Why might that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default edge width is smaller than the resolution of the figure. You can fix this by increasing its size via the `output_size` option of `graph_draw()`, or by passing to it the parmeter `edge_pen_width` with an appropriately large value.